# Angular2: overwrite img command in ng2-ckeditor

Tags: angular, ngx-modal

I have a page that have ckeditor in there. I use ng2-ckeditor and ngx-modal.
This is my template:

```
<div>
    <ckeditor 
        id="questionContent"
        name="questionContent"
        [(ngModel)]="question.content" 
        (change)="onChange($event)" 
        (ready)="onReady($event)"
        (focus)="onFocus($event)" 
        (blur)="onBlur($event)" debounce="500">
    </ckeditor>
</div>
....//Some stuff there
<!--Modal-->
<modal #uploadModal [closeOnEscape]="false" [closeOnOutsideClick]="false">
    <modal-header>
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{ 'QUESTIONS' | translate }}</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-content>
        <div class="drag-n-drop-container"
            ngFileDrop
            [options]="options"
            (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)"
            [ngClass]="{'file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
            (onFileOver)="fileOverBase($event)">
        <h1>Drag & Drop</h1>
        <label class="upload-button">
            <input type="file"
                class="hidden"
                ngFileSelect
                [options]="options"
                (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)">
            Browse
        </label>
        </div>
    </modal-content>
    <modal-footer>
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-right cancel" (click)="uploadModal.close()">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            {{ 'BUTTON_CLOSE' | translate }}</button>
    </modal-footer>
</modal>
```

My situation is try to overwrite image dialog of ckeditor. So in my component I will do this:

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren, AfterViewChecked,
  AfterViewInit, Renderer, QueryList, ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Modal } from 'ngx-modal';
import { CKButtonDirective, CKEditorComponent } from 'ng2-ckeditor';

declare var CKEDITOR: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'question-edit',
  templateUrl: './question-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './question-edit.style.css'
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class EditQuestionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('answers') answerInputs: QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChild('uploadModal') public uploadModal: Modal;

  private editor: any;
  constructor(private rd: Renderer) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  };

  registerCKEditorCommands(editor: any, uploadModal: Modal) {
    let self = this;
    editor.addCommand("image", {
      exec: self.onUploadImage
    });
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      for (var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        self.editor = CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName];
        self.editor.on("instanceReady", function (ev: any) {
          let _editor = ev.editor;
          self.registerCKEditorCommands(_editor, self.uploadModal);
        });
      }
    });
  };

  onUploadImage(editor: any) {
    this.uploadModal.open();
  };
}
```

All work fine except when I click image button in ckeditor toolbar. It will invoke function `onUploadImage()` but `this.uploadModal` is `undefined`. If we try to printout `this.uploadModal` in function `ngAfterViewInit()` it give correct value and we can open dialog there.

How I can handle open dialog in function `onUploadImage`?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think any of these options should work for you because this way context will be referenced to your component instance:

1) bind

a)

```
editor.addCommand("image", {
  exec: this.onUploadImage.bind(this)
});
```

b)

```
export class EditQuestionComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.onUploadImage = this.onUploadImage.bind(this);
  }
  ...
  editor.addCommand("image", {
    exec: this.onUploadImage
  });
```

2) arrow function

```
editor.addCommand("image", {
  exec: (editor) => this.onUploadImage(editor)
});
```

3) instance arrow function

```
editor.addCommand("image", {
  exec: this.onUploadImage
});
...
onUploadImage = (editor: any) => {
  this.uploadModal.open();
};
```

See also

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Comment: Thank for your kindly reply. The bind solution makes the uploadModal is not `undefined`. But it does not open the modal dialog correctly. It just show the backdrop modal with shadow.

Comment: Can you create plunker?

Comment: Btw. I apply your solution with `bind(this)` and I change the third party `ngx-modal` to `ng2-bootstrap` and it help. So your solution should work fine. And `ngx-modal` does not handle well for that case. Thank you so much.